How to click link in powerbi it auto to just open by edge
I have list of link web in powerbi table. How can I do when I click a link, it just open by edge. I don't want to set default web browser because someone want see report in chrome or firefox, but thoese link web just run well in microsoft edge. Please help me how to do
I just use syntax microsoft-edge:https://weblink but can't set it a URL web
